# Posicionamento de uma div

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-3

Boa Noite, 
Estou criando um site e queria fazer um layout como se fosse xadrez, uma div preta ao lado uma branca e em baixo o contrario, o único problema é que ao diminuir para celular era pra ficar uma preta e uma branca e outra preta e outra branca. 
só que a div branca não inverte oque faz com que fique duas brancas ao meio. Quero que a div2 fique encima da div

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="div1">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <a class="#" href="#"><img src="#" /> </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="div2">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <p class="text-justify ">
                Lorem Ipsum 
            </p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vc esta usando Bootstrap 3 ou 4? Pelas classes do seu código me parece o 4, mas vc colocou a tag `Bootstrap-3` na pergunta... vc precisa dar a certeza de qual versão está usando!

Answer (score 1):

Esse é um problema bem interessante e você pode perceber com ele como às vezes trabalhar com height pode ser divertido.

Como você quer um layout tipo xadrez, responsivamente não podemos garantir que ao diminuir a tela os quadrados fiquem posicionados exatamente como especificamos. Uma maneira fácil de conseguir isso é usando `.d-flex .flex-wrap` do Bootstrap em um container. Então os 8 itens irão manter suas posições com um `width calc(100% / 8)`  que dá 12.5% de largura do bloco. Mas isso não resolve o problema, porque depende de como você quer que fique o formato do xadrez, se diminui a quantidade de colunas ou não.

Sobre a altura, você pode fazer um estudo por view-port e analisar qual seria a melhor maneira de defini-la. Depois fazer as modificações por media queries.

Um exemplo básico que montei e pode te ajudar:

```css
 .item-line {
        height: 138.75px;
      }
      .item-box {
        position: relative;
        float: left;        
        width: 12.5%; /* calc(100% / 8)*/
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .item-line:nth-child(even) .item-box:nth-child(even) {background: lime}
      .item-line:nth-child(even) .item-box:nth-child(odd) {background: fuchsia}      
      .item-line:nth-child(odd) .item-box:nth-child(even) {background: fuchsia}
      .item-line:nth-child(odd) .item-box:nth-child(odd) {background: lime}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap item-line">
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap item-line">
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap item-line">
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap item-line">
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
      <div class="item-box">Flex item</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Existem diferentes formas de fazer o que você precisa, algumas delas:

- Você pode reorganizar os elementos de acordo com o dispositivo, fazendo uso da [propriedade *order* do flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#reordering);
- Você pode utilizar os [utilitários de *display*](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) do Bootstrap e ocultar os itens que fogem da ordem desejada (de acordo com o dispositivo);

Espero ter ajudado.